# テキストエリアへの入力内容をリアルタイムに処理して別のテキストエリアに反映させたい

Tags: javascript

Google 翻訳のように、左に打ち込んだ内容を即座に右に反映するといったことを行いたいのですが、それらを行うためにはどういった技術（適したプログラミング言語）が使われていて、どのように作られているのかの概要を教えていたただきたく思います。

まったく手掛かりがつかめていないので、ちょっとしたキーワードなどもご教授いただければ幸いです。
ちなみに、Google 翻訳以外ではdeeplなどが私が求めているものになります。

Comment: 「翻訳」がメインではないと思うので、より内容にあったタイトルに変更してみました。

Comment: なんと素晴らしい気遣いを。。！
ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

index.htmlの内容

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>HTML</title>
  
  <!-- HTML -->
  

  <!-- Custom Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="10" id="input"></textarea>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="10" id="output"
  <!-- Project -->
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.cssの内容

```css
body {
    font-size: 15pt;
}

.input {float: left;}
.output {float: right;}
```

main.jsの内容

```javascript
input = document.querySelector('#input');
output = document.querySelector('#output');
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  input_data = input.value;
  output.value = input_data;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event#text_input_element

input 要素の onInput イベントでキー入力ごとにハンドラーを呼び出せます
あとは input DOM から value を出し入れするだけで実現できます

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function f(e) {
  output.value = e.value;
}
```

```html
入力<input type="text" onInput="f(this)" />
<br>
出力<input type="text" id="output" />
```

Comment: onInputなるものがあるのは初めて知りました。。
参考にさせて頂きます。
ありがとうございました！